# Alternative to overridePendingTransition() - Android

Tags: android, animation

I just discovered the android overrivePendingTransition() method. It works fine but I have the following problem :

In the Settings/Dislpay menu, you can choose to show no animations, some animations or all animations, and the method only works when it is set to all animations.

Can I bypass that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings you're talking about are user preferences. If one of your users wanted to turn off all animations, why would you want to find a workaround to continue showing animations in your app? It doesn't seem very user-friendly.

At any rate, `overridePendingTransition` is used to animate between `Activities`, as opposed to `Views` which is part of why you can turn them off, and was introduced in **Android 2.0**. There isn't another SDK method available that does the same thing; however, you can try using a `LayoutAnimation` to animate the layout you provide for each `Activity` you're creating. It wouldn't be exactly the same as `overridePendingTransition`, but I think it's going to be one of the closest things you'll find to an alternative.

**your_animation.xml**:

```
<layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:animation="@anim/THE_ANIMATION_YOU_WANT_TO_USE" />
```

**your_layout.xml**:

```
android:layoutAnimation="@anim/your_animation"
```

Comment: You're right about being user-friendly, so I am gonna leave it like this, thank you!

Comment: If the application is a game, you don't want the user turning off the activity transitions because it might be detrimental for the user experience. And they would't know that the ugly screen transitions were because they turned off that preference.

Comment: what the decision is for compose?

Answer (score 0):

### Handling `overridePendingTransition` Deprecation in Android

The `overridePendingTransition` method is deprecated in Android. Below are some alternatives using the Transition framework and custom animations:

#### Slide-in from right:

```kotlin
val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, ReferActivity::class.java)
val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle()
startActivity(i, options)
```

#### Custom Animation with Specific Effects:

```kotlin
val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, ReferActivity::class.java)
val options = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(this, R.anim.enter_anim, R.anim.exit_anim).toBundle()
startActivity(i, options)
```

Example `enter_anim.xml` for Slide-in Animation from Right to Left:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <translate
       android:fromXDelta="100%"
       android:toXDelta="0%"
       android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

Example `exit_anim.xml` for Slide-out Animation to the Right:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <translate
       android:fromXDelta="0%"
       android:toXDelta="100%"
       android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

###### To achieve seamless activity transitions, leverage the Transition framework's flexibility for custom effects, ensuring animations are stored in the `res/anim` directory.