# Animate activity exit transition with pivot- alternative to overridePendingTransition()

Tags: android, android-animation

First of all not duplicate of : [Alternative to overridePendingTransition() - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353840/alternative-to-overridependingtransition-android)

I want to scale an activity (exit) with a pivot point. The problem is that the xml pivotX & pivotY values use pixels which makes things difficult. So overridePendingTransition() is not really helpful because it only uses a xml animation.

So I want to animate the scale-exit of an activity (from 1f to 0f scaling rate) with a pivot of 50dp of the right of the screen and 100dp from the bottom of the screen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to start a transparent Activity and make your animation from here

Look at [Android Developers Activity Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhiPJByIMrM#t=65) where they explain the old custom/manual Activity Transition.